# Changing the values at X axis in morris linear graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, morris.js

I wrote a simple morris linear graph to capture how much has been collected at particular timing.
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvdn7xLa/2/
**`Morris js code:`**

```
Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-example',
  data: [{
    y: '6.30AM',
    a: 20
  }, {
    y: '7.30AM',
    a: 40
  }, {
    y: '8.30AM',
    a: 60
  }, {
    y: '9.30AM',
    a: 80
  }, {
    y: '10.30AM',
    a: 100
  }, {
    y: '11.30AM',
    a: 120
  }, {
    y: '12.30PM',
    a: 140
  }],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['Amount collected']
});
```

However `time` values aren't appearing in `X-axis`. Some unrelated years are appearing. If I change `xkey: 'y', ykeys: ['a']` to `xkey: ['a'], ykeys: 'y'`, then I get weird results like

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Amount collected: 6.3
```

How can I make time values appear at `X-axis`?

Comment: I don't believe your `x` values are legal according to the docs. But I don't have any experience with Morris.

Comment: You mean that I can't use decimals in morris graphs?

Comment: I mean that Morris is looking for timestamps in the form of millisecond timestamps (as returned by Date.getTime() or as strings in the following formats:
`2012`,
`2012 Q1`,

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for explaining...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
parseTime: false
```

into your chart configuration.

This will

> skip time/date parsing for X values, instead treating them as an
>   equally-spaced series.

Otherwise you would need to adjust your "x" values to either milliseconds or a valid Date/Time string that can be parsed

> A string containing the name of the attribute that contains date (X)
>   values.  Timestamps are accepted in the form of millisecond timestamps
>   (as returned by Date.getTime() or as strings in the following formats:
>
> - 2012
> - 2012 Q1
> - 2012 W1
> - 2012-02
> - 2012-02-24
> - 2012-02-24 15:00
> - 2012-02-24 15:00:00
> - 2012-02-24 15:00:00.000

http://jsbin.com/walekitori/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Would you mind accepting this as the answer if it solves your problem? If not I will gladly try helping with anything else.

Comment: This solution works 100%. I was about to remove morris chart because couldn't find a way to display non-time values on the x-axis such as country names but this simple trick saved my day. Thanks genius